# How can I fix timeseries with TimescaleDB?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I have data like this:

```
Month_event | No_people | Cost
2017-03-01  | 78        | 120000 
2017-01-01  | 67        | 220000 
2017-07-01  | 121       | 320000 
2017-04-01  | 70        | 100000
```

and what I normally do from my code is using a SQL query (windowed) in Postgresql to add the missing values in the timeseries (copy over the value from the month before):

```
Month_event | No_people | Cost
2017-01-01  | 67        | 220000 
2017-02-01  | 67        | 220000 
2017-03-01  | 78        | 120000 
2017-04-01  | 70        | 100000 
2017-05-01  | 70        | 100000  
2017-06-01  | 70        | 100000 
2017-07-01  | 121       | 320000
```

This is my usual query:

```
WITH 
calendar AS (
    SELECT interval_date::date FROM generate_series('2005-01-01'::date, (select release_month from mtd), '1 month'::interval) interval_date
),
m AS (
    SELECT *, LEAD(monthly_event) OVER (ORDER BY monthly_event) AS next_date
    FROM my_data
)
SELECT *
FROM calendar c
JOIN m
    ON c.interval_date BETWEEN m.monthly_date AND
    (CASE WHEN m.next_date IS NULL THEN date_trunc('month', current_date) ELSE m.next_date - '1 month'::interval END);
```

As Postgres extension, I can reuse the same query on TimescaleDB I suppose.
I am wondering if there is better performing solution for TimescaleDB as I cannot figure it out from the documentation.

Comment: sounds like [GapFilling](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.0/using-timescaledb/reading-data#gap-filling) to me

Comment: let me have a look, but it sounds like what I need, thanks. Totally missed from the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some new functions for that in TimescaleDB 1.2, see: https://blog.timescale.com/sql-functions-for-time-series-analysis/ The gap filling stuff should do what you're looking for much more easily.

Comment: Wondering if there is any plan about TimescaleDB + GPU